# Set UIToolbarPosition for created UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uitoolbar

I'm writing app which is aimed only for iOS5 devices, so I'm trying to maximize usage of new `appearance` API.

I can change background of my `UIToolbar` with following method:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:<myImage> forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Everything works fine, but I'm looking for more customization, so I was wondering about usage of `UIToolbarPosition` and I run into some problems. Using InterfaceBuilder or adding `UIToolbar` programmatically I'm positioning it at the top of main view - so I'm expecting `UIToolbarPosition` to be set as `UIToolbarPositionTop`, but from what I'm testing it doesn't work automaticly nor can I find any API which allows me to set `UIToolbarPosition` (Yes, I googled it already).

So - main question - how to create `UIToolbar` and tag it properly, so it can response only to `UIToolbarPositionTop` or `UIToolbarPositionBottom`, so I can use:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:<myImage_1> forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionTop barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:<myImage_2> forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**EDIT:** More details, as asked.

I have multiply toolbars in my application - for instance, toolbars at top of the screen on 2 screens, toolbars acting as accessory views for keyboard and 2 toolbars at the bottom of modals screens. I'd like to maximize usage of new appearance API instead of customizing toolbars on each screens, hence I'm asking about whole UIToolbarPosition thing and how to use it.

I know I can achieve what I want just by customizing each UIToolbar separately, but I'm just curious about new API and UIToolbarPosition usage.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you making a toolbar that can be either on the top or bottom and changes its appearance accordingly? Just add a little detail about what you hope to accomplish and it'll be much easier to help you find a solution.

Comment: I have multiply toolbars in my application - for instance, toolbars at top of the screen on 2 screens, toolbars acting as accessory views for keyboard and 2 toolbars at the bottom of modals screens. 
I'd like to maximize usage of new appearance API instead of customizing toolbars on each screens, hence I'm asking about whole UIToolbarPosition thing and how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIToolbarPostion` isn't a property that you're supposed to be setting programmatically - instead, it allows you to tell the program how to handle a toolbar when it's in different positions. This is mostly for toolbars that are getting pushed around by screen changes (autorotation) or are on something like a navigation controller that has variable content.

That being said, if you want to directly access your toolbars so that you can use them/set properties/etc there are a couple of methods. It sounds like you know what tagging is, and this is a valid method - just give the toolbar a tag in IB or programmatically (either edit the tag property in the side bar for IB or use the `.tag` property when you declare the toolbar). Then you can use the `viewWithTag` method to access your toolbar. However, a better method would be to just create an IB property for the toolbar (same as with labels or buttons) by control-dragging over to the header file from the toolbar. Then you could just write `[nameOfToolbarProperty doSomeMethod]`. If you're creating your toolbar with code then just make a reference to it the same way e.g.

`UIToolbar *tref = [/*toolbar creation code*/];`

In conclusion, your code

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:<myImage_1> forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionTop barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

could be made to work by adding

```
//Connect this to your toolbar in Interface Builder
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *tref;
```

to your header. Then just do

```
 [tref setBackgroundImage:<myImage_1> forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionTop barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Note that this just tells the program what image to display if the toolbar is in the top position - it does not set the position of the toolbar. `UIToolbarPosition` is a constant (so you cannot set it).

Comment: Thank You for your extensive guidelines, I'm mostly using UBOutlets, so last approach seems most suitable for my needs.

Can You just clarify for me one thing more? 

Do You know exactly when UIToolbar is in UIToolbarPositionTop or UIToolbarPositionBottom - I tried to move UIToolbar to top or bottom of my views both in IB and programaticly, but neither worked for me - moving UIToolbar to top of the screen doesn't mean that it has UIToolbarPositionTop.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `UIToolbarPosition` constant is really meant to be used by the system, not the developer. If the system moves the toolbar (through rotation, etc) then it uses what you defined to change the appearance. If you really need to be able to set the appearance of the toolbar yourself by moving it, consider subclassing `UIToolbar` and telling it to check its position when it's moved and update its image accordingly.