# UIToolbar appearance for programmatically added tool bars

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar, uiappearance

I have two `UIToolbar` instances, one added at the top of the screen, one at the bottom. I'd like to style these using iOS 5 appearance protocol.

I can get the following to work:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbarimage.png"]
                            forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

However, I am unable to get `UIToolbarPositionTop` or `UIToolbarPositionBottom` working with my programatically added toolbars. I am creating the tool bars like this:

```
_topBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
_topBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview: _topBar];

_bottomBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    _bottomBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview: _bottomBar];
```

As I understand it, UIToolbarPositionTop works fine with interface builder files, but does anyone know a way to get them working programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a relatively simple fix. Rather than using the general

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbarimage.png"]
                        forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny
                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

One can target specific toolbars as such:

```
// Setup top tool bar
UIToolbar *topToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[topToolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_toolbar.png"]
               forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Setup bottom toolbar
UIToolbar *bottomToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[bottomToolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom_toolbar.png"]
               forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I found a similar answer, with some details about why `UIToolbarPositionTop` etc are system properties and shouldn't be relied upon [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612512/816002).